# Автоматическое обновление приложений android через командную строку

Tags: android, консоль, shell, termux

Как в терминале android (например: *Termux*) одной командой запустить автоматическое обновление приложений из PlayMarket?
Данные:

- Package: '*com.android.vending*';
- Class: '*com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity*';
- Action: '*com.google.android.finsky.VIEW_MY_DOWNLOADS*';
- '*trigger_update_all:true*'.

Как открыть активити '*моих приложений*' понятно:

`am start -n com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.MainActivity -a com.google.android.finsky.VIEW_MY_DOWNLOADS`

, а вот как нажать кнопку '*обновить всё*' ('*trigger_update_all*').

Comment: Как насчет `adb shell input tap x y`? Вместо `x` и `y` подставьте координаты, где находится кнопка в пикселях.

Comment: Хотел одной командой и без ADB. Типа `am start ... -c trigger_update_all -f 1` , но я не уверен в правильности.

Comment: А если так: `am start ... && input tap ...`? Такой вариант вам не подходит?

Comment: Без root-прав `input tap` требует разрешение _java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission_ , но выдать его не возможно _Package com.termux has not requested permission android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться командой `input tap`, чтобы сымитировать клик по какой-то точке, указав значения в пикселях. Например, команду можно написать так:

```bash
am start ... && sleep 3 && input tap 300 1250
```

Вместо чисел `300 1250` вам нужно подставить другие значения, в зависимости от конфигрурации вашего телефона и расположения кнопки.

Не самый надежный способ, но не уверен, что есть способ лучше.

Comment: Без root-прав `input tap` требует разрешение _java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission_, но выдать его не возможно _Package com.termux has not requested permission android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS_.